# Not able to start Confluent Kafka on Windows subsystem for Linux(WSL)

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux, confluent-platform, wsl-2

I am trying to install Confluent on Windows using WSL. I have done most of the setup as described here, but I am facing the following error while trying to start confluence

```
sai@DESKTOP-IRLOG8O:~$ confluent local services start
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.266515
Error: fork/exec /mnt/c/jdk-15.0.2/bin/java: no such file or directory
```

This is my JAVA_HOME

```
sai@DESKTOP-IRLOG8O:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/mnt/c/jdk-15.0.2
```

Which also means that I have Java on my windows machine in path ***C:\jdk-15.0.2***

Inside my WSL bash, I am able to see file *java* under path ***/mnt/c/jdk-15.0.2/bin***

I am not sure what is the issue here? Please help resolve this. Let me know if any other details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Somehow, the space in my JAVA_HOME path was not getting resolved properly. I moved the JDK path on my Windows machine to a path without any spaces and the issue was resolved. The WSL Linux host uses the JAVA_HOME path as mounted in /mnt/c/<PATH_TO_JDK_ON_WINDOWS_HOST>